# WPF Mediaelement LoadedBehavior does't work correctly?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mediaelement

I am creating a simple app in WPF with VB.NET code behind. This code works perfectly. After the choosing of file, the function returns the correct numbers according to media type, the note image appears when the media is audio file and disappears when not. The media plays automatically. However I don't need to play the media automatically and when I set LoadedBehavior to Manual (instead of the default Play), strange things happen. The MediaOpened event is fired from time to time, the function returns sometimes zero, sometimes correct number, sometimes incorrect number. I am googling almost three days and I've found nothing. I'd like to make MediaElement.Play and MediaElement.Pause to show the first frame of video/image, but it's not possible without LoadedBehavior set to manual. I'd like to avoid LoadedBehavior somehow. Could someone give me a hint, please? Thank you very much in advance.

```
Private Sub btnFile_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnFile.Click
        Try
            Me.MediaElementSetting.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual
            Me.MediaElementSetting.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Close
            Me.MediaElementSetting.Stop()
            Me.MediaElementSetting.Close()
            Me.PvwTimer.Stop()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'The exception occurs when LoadedBehavior is not set to manual, that's why it's unused
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Dim ArrayIndes as Integer = 1
        OpenFileDialog(ArrayIndex)
End Sub

Sub OpenFileDialog(ByVal ArrayIndex As Integer)
        Dim Dlg1 As New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        Dlg1.ShowDialog()
        If Dlg1.FileName <> "" Then
            strFile = Dlg1.FileName
            Me.MediaElementSetting.Source = New Uri(strFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub MediaElementSetting_MediaOpened(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MediaElementSetting.MediaOpened
        Dim t As Integer = AV()
End Sub

Function AV() As Integer
        'Check, if the media has timespan (if it is image, audio, video w sound, video w/o sound - image has video without timespan)
        If Me.MediaElementSetting.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan = True Then
            If Me.MediaElementSetting.HasAudio = True Then
                If Me.MediaElementSetting.HasVideo = True Then
                    'Media is a video with sound
                    MediaInfo = 4
                Else
                    'Media is an audio
                    MediaInfo = 2
                End If
            Else
                If Me.MediaElementSetting.HasVideo = True Then
                    'Media is a video without sound
                    MediaInfo = 3
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If Me.MediaElementSetting.HasVideo = True Then
                'Media is an image
                MediaInfo = 1
            End If
        End If

        If MediaInfo = 2 Then
            'Note is an image in a window. When the media is an audio it covers the mediaelement in a window
            Note.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        Else
            Note.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        End If
        
        Return MediaInfo
    End Function
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `btnFile_Click`?

Comment: The purpose of the button is to (I hope) close all the stuff and display the OpenFileDialog again. Sorry, I missed a line of code. I put it back. Now it opens the OpenFileDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I accidentally found the solution, that works perfectly for me. **To don't use MediaElement.LoadedBehavior = Manual at all**

```
Private Sub MediaElementSetting_MediaOpened(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MediaElementSetting.MediaOpened
    Dim t As Integer = AV()
    Me.MediaElementSetting.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Close
    Me.MediaElementSetting.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play
    Me.MediaElementSetting.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Pause
End Sub
```

And to control media with MediaElement.LoadedBehavior as well. This works for me perfectly, even when I think it's not correct. Logically, LoadedBehavior means loaded behavior.

```
Sub PlayMedia()
    MediaElementSetting.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play
End Sub
Sub PauseMedia()
    MediaElementSetting.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Pause
End Sub
Sub StopMedia()
    MediaElementSetting.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: if you set `ScrubbingEnabled=true` you dont need to set `LoadedBehavior` to `Play`

Comment: @Julien not longer true if I don't set LoadedBehavior to Manual I get an exception, (System.NotSupportedException: 'Cannot control media unless LoadedBehavior or UnloadedBehavior is set to Manual.'
) regardless my mp3 audio quit working silently no error is generated.

Comment: OT: Sorry...     Which version of VS are you using??? I am still using VS 2012.5 for such simple apps. I prefer when the .NET framework is a part of system and/or Windows updates and to distribute just the executable files. No setup packages. No new registry entries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VB.NET person, but here is a working example in C#.

Here's the XAML. I have a `MediaElement`, a `Border` as a stand-in for the notes image, and a button.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElementSetting"
            Margin="16" />
        <Border x:Name="AudioElement"
            Margin="16"
            Background="Red"
            Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="AUDIO" />
        </Border>
        <Button x:Name="FileButton"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="16"
            Padding="8,4"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="FileButton_OnClick"
            Content="File" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the code-behind.

I'm initializing the `MediaElement` once in the constructor of the window.

In order to show the first frame of the video, I need to set `ScrubbingEnabled = true`.

In `OpenFileDialog()`, after setting the `Source` I call `SetupMedia` which immediately calls `Play`, `Pause`, and then sets the `Position`. This ensures that the `MediaOpened` event gets called.

In the `OnMediaOpened` handler, I call `GetMediaInfo` which is like your `AV` function and instead of returning an integer, I return an enum instead.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool isMediaOpened;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MediaElementSetting.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            MediaElementSetting.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
            MediaElementSetting.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Close;
            MediaElementSetting.MediaOpened += OnMediaOpened;
        }

        private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isMediaOpened = true;
            var mediaInfo = GetMediaInfo();
            Debug.WriteLine($"{mediaInfo}");
        }

        private void SetupMedia()
        {
            MediaElementSetting.Play();
            MediaElementSetting.Pause();
            MediaElementSetting.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        }

        private MediaInfo GetMediaInfo()
        {
            var mediaInfo = MediaInfo.None;

            if (MediaElementSetting.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
            {
                if (MediaElementSetting.HasAudio)
                {
                    mediaInfo = MediaElementSetting.HasVideo ? MediaInfo.VideoWithSound : MediaInfo.Audio;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MediaElementSetting.HasVideo)
                    {
                        mediaInfo = MediaInfo.VideoNoSound;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (MediaElementSetting.HasVideo)
                {
                    mediaInfo = MediaInfo.Image;
                }
            }

            AudioElement.Visibility = mediaInfo == MediaInfo.Audio ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

            return mediaInfo;
        }

        private void FileButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog();
        }

        private void OpenFileDialog()
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            
            dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dialog.FileName))
            {
                if (isMediaOpened)
                {
                    MediaElementSetting.Source = null;
                    isMediaOpened = false;
                }

                MediaElementSetting.Source = new Uri(dialog.FileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                SetupMedia();
            }
        }

        public enum MediaInfo
        {
            None = 0,
            Image = 1,
            Audio = 2,
            VideoNoSound = 3,
            VideoWithSound = 4
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's almost done. However, it doesn't work correctly with audio files. When I step into the code, everything works perfectly, audio only file is correctly detected, red square is displayed. When I run the code without stepping into, it ignores the audio detection. All other media files are detected correctly. The previews work also correctly. Do you have any idea, why the audio only files are not detected?

Comment: I'm not sure. I tested with mp3 files and everything works fine on my end.

Comment: @JaroslavBach did you resolve why your mp3/audio silently NOT working? 9 years later this  MICROSOFT STRANGE problem appears all of a sudden in my code. Using VS2019

Comment: @Meryan I've accidentally replied regarding VS to your second post in this thread. To be honest, I haven't time to continue in this project. In the meantime I had to learn PHP, jQuery, MySQL because of projects I was hired to. Now, I have one more project in PHP, one more in .NET and then I'll try to get back to my app.